# angle between 2-D vectors (knowing inner product and length of vectorial product)

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, physics

I'm struggling with the following exercise:

Given the 2-D vectors $<A>$ and $<B>$, where their inner product $<A> \cdot <B> = -6$ and the magnitude of the vectorial product is $ \parallel <A> \times <B> \parallel= 9$ ; **find the angle between them**.

- I know that the inner product is equal to $\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel \cos(\Theta)$, $\Theta$ being the angle between the vectors.
- I also know that the magnitude of the vectorial product is $\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel \sin(\Theta)$.

So I started reasoning like this:

$$ -6 = \parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel \cos(\Theta) $$
$$ \frac{(-6)}{\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel} =  \cos(\Theta) $$
$$ (\frac{(-6)}{\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel})^2 =  (\cos(\Theta))^2 $$

And then did the same with the length of the vectorial product:

$$ 9 = \parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel \sin(\Theta) $$
$$ \frac{9}{\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel} = \sin(\Theta) $$
$$ (\frac{9}{\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel})^2 = (\sin(\Theta))^2 $$

Finally I tried to use both formulas and the trigonometric identity $\left(\sin(\Theta)\right)^2 + \left(\cos(\Theta)\right)^2 = 1$ to get the value of the vectors' lengths multiplied together.

$$ (\frac{(-6)}{\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel})^2 + (\frac{9}{\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel})^2 = (\sin(\Theta))^2 + (\cos(\Theta))^2 $$
$$ (\frac{(-6)}{\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel})^2 + (\frac{9}{\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel})^2 = 1 $$
$$ \frac{36}{(\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel)^2} + \frac{81}{(\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel)^2} = 1 $$
$$ \frac{36 + 81}{(\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel)^2} = 1 $$
$$ \frac{117}{(\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel)^2} = 1 $$
$$ 117 = (\parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel)^2 $$
$$  \parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel = \sqrt{117} $$

Knowing that $  \parallel A\parallel\parallel B\parallel = \sqrt{117} $ I just plugged that in in the inner and vectorial product formulas.

$$ \sqrt{117} * \cos((\Theta)) = -6 $$
$$  \cos((\Theta)) = \frac{-6}{\sqrt{117}} $$
$$ (\Theta) = \arccos (\frac{-6}{\sqrt{117}}) $$

Same with the length of the vectorial product:

$$ \sqrt{117} * \sin((\Theta)) = 9 $$
$$  \sin((\Theta)) = \frac{9}{\sqrt{117}} $$
$$ (\Theta) = \arcsin (\frac{9}{\sqrt{117}}) $$

**And here is what I don't understand:**

$$ \arccos (\frac{-6}{\sqrt{117}}) \neq \arcsin (\frac{9}{\sqrt{117}}) $$

Since $ \arcsin (\frac{9}{\sqrt{117}}) \approx 56  $(degrees) and $ \arccos (\frac{-6}{\sqrt{117}}) \approx 124 $ (degrees).

The textbook gives 124 degrees as the correct answer but I don't understand. **Why am I getting 2 results for the same angle? Why is 124 the correct one? Did I make a mistake?**

Comment: $\arcsin(9/\sqrt(117)) = 124 \mbox{ or } 56$ and since the inner product is negative it must be $\arccos(-6/\sqrt(117)) = 124$ the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\lvert A\times B\lvert}{A\cdot B}=\frac{\lvert A \lvert\cdot\lvert B\lvert\sin\theta}{\lvert A \lvert\cdot\lvert B\lvert\cos\theta}=\tan\theta=\frac{9}{-6}$$
then
$$\theta=\arctan(-3/2)$$
then how the dot product is negative,the angle is between 90 and 180 degrees, we have:

$$\theta=180+\arctan(-3/2)=180-56=124$$